# configure: error: Missing required libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, compilation, mingw, msys

I'm Trying to Compile a project that's need `curllib` on windows xp 32-bit

i've downloaded "`curl-7.35.0.tar.gz`" and compiled it, copied "`libcurl.m4`" and "`curl-config`"

when i run this command in MSYS Shell:

```
LIBCURL="-lcurldll" ./configure CFLAGS="-O3"
```

It Gives me this Error:

```
configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2
```

i know that i hadn't installed the curl lib properly in my system that's why this error shows up

can someone tell me the right way to install libcurl in windows ? ( Note: I'm a newbie with C/C++ and compiling and all related things )

Thanks in advance !

configure script results:

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-w64-mingw32
checking target system type... i686-w64-mingw32
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 needs -traditional... no
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc -std=gnu99... gcc3
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/endian.h usability... no
checking sys/endian.h presence... no
checking for sys/endian.h... no
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... no
checking syslog.h presence... no
checking for syslog.h... no
checking for sys/sysctl.h... no
checking whether be32dec is declared... no
checking whether le32dec is declared... no
checking whether be32enc is declared... no
checking whether le32enc is declared... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... no
checking for alloca... yes
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking whether we can compile AVX code... yes
checking whether we can compile XOP code... yes
checking whether we can compile AVX2 code... yes
checking for json_loads in -ljansson... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthreadGC2... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthreadGC1... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthreadGC... no
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for curl-config... /mingw/bin/curl-config
checking for the version of libcurl... 7.35.0
checking for libcurl >= version 7.15.2... yes
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the libcurl you downloaded/compiled in the linkers path. This means you need to take the libcurl.dll file (not the m4) and put it in the directory that the linker will search in. Usually the projects directory or one of the system libraries that are defined by default in Windows.